# creating facebook style timeline in ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook-timeline

I am trying to creating something similar to facebook timeline in facebook website. I tried searching for some examples I could not find any. Can anyone give me pointers on how to get started if I want to create one or an existing example would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I think this could be done using UICollectionView in combination with your custom layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but a **pointer**, If you'd thinking to make something like [here](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline), then its kind of tough and really need presence of mind to make it. First of all, source code is only avail with *Mark Zuckerburg* so in case you can ask him for that. If he'll deny, you should go ahead and,

*Think of it, design of it, and start making it.*

You need to make mocktail of `UITableView`'s, `UIImageView`'s, extra `UILabel`'s and `UIButton`'s for garnishing and test, and a well looking design that says yes its timeline.

Once you done with above, you need some test data, with a `date` inside it, perform `descending` sort with `NSSortDescriptor`. Update your timeline with those data you've. You've to check for the kind of data you want, or you've included. Set the layout as per the data you want to show.

and you'll say, Whoa! I've own timeline.